# Commutator property proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I am working through Griffiths, and about a chapter or so ago, I came across the following commutator identity: $$[AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B$$ I tried to prove this rule by calculating the commutator and applying it to a function as follows: $$LHS: ABC(f) - CAB(f)$$ $$RHS: ABC(f) - ACB(f) + AC(f)B - CA(f)B$$ Now, I see that the $ABC(f)$ terms cancel, but my confusion is with the remaining terms. I see that if we "drop" the function right here, then the order of the $ACB(f)$ and $AC(f)B$ terms would allow them to cancel, but these two, with a function in them, are not equal. I tried to imagine three operators and to prove that the position of the function within the operators does matter as follows: $A = \frac{d}{dx}$, $B =$ identity, and $C = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. If we calculate $AfBC$, $ABfC$, and $ABCf$, then we get $f'\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$, $f'\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$, and $f'''$ respectively.

Of course, I have seen the proof that goes like this: $$A[B,C] + [A,C]B = ABC - ACB + ACB - CAB = ABC- CAB = [AB,C]$$ but my differential geometry professor told me to never calculate commutators this way and to always apply and drop a function. Thus, I am confused why I cant get to the results with the "apply and drop" approach outlined above. If someone could give me a hint that would be helpful.

Note: I am proving this to myself to apply the result to another problem - this isn't a homework question.

Comment: If you apply the given operator to a function $f$, as you do, you have the function on the right of the operator, as you have on the LHS and in the first part of the RHS. Where did you get the idea of inserting $f$ in the middle of a product on the RHS?

Comment: okay, maybe i see the issue. so if I am applying $[A,B]C$ to a function, I was thinking that the commutator here is [A,B], so we apply this to $f$. do you mean the proper thing to do is to keep the function fully on the outside and do $ABCf - BACf$? @kricheli

Comment: Yes, if you have $f$ fully on the outside on the LHS, then you need to do the same on the RHS. And if you want to apply the commutator $\left[A,B\right]$ to a function, that function will be $Cf$. ;)

Comment: thank you very much ! @kricheli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote $$LHS: ABC(f) - CAB(f)$$ $$RHS: ABC(f) - ACB(f) + AC(f)B - CA(f)B$$ But when applying the commutator, it should actually be $$RHS: ABC(f) - ACB(f) + ACB(f) - CAB(f)$$ because $[A,C]B = (AC-CA)B(f) = ACB(f) - CAB(f)$, then as you can see, the terms $ACB(f)$ and $ACB(f)$ cancel out.